# syncronize two objects and apply new values

Tags: javascript, object, ramda.js

What I want to achieve is basically this:

```
R.mergeDeepRight(
  { age: 40, contact: { email: 'baa@example.com' }},
  { name: 'fred', age: 10, contact: { email: 'moo@example.com' }}
);
```

but without the `{ name: 'fred' }` in the resulting object.

Only keys in the first object should apply.

Comment: Do you want solution with pure js or only ramda?

Comment: any solution would be appreciated. I thought ramda is best suited for this purpose.
I should have mentioned that I want to omit any key in the second object that doesn't exist in the first. I guess that's tough :/

Comment: @RaJoB you can filter the keys from second object and put in `omit( [ filtered keys]...` or you can use simply pick i have added that too in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a reusable function combining [`mergeDeepRight`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeDeepRight), [`pick`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick), and [`keys`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#keys), like this:

```js
const funkyMerge = (o1, o2) =>   
  mergeDeepRight(o1, pick(keys(o1), o2))

console.log(funkyMerge(
  { age: 40, contact: { email: 'baa@example.com' }},
  { name: 'fred', age: 10, contact: { email: 'moo@example.com' }}
))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {mergeDeepRight, pick, keys} = ramda      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**omit**](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit) after [**mergeDeepRight**](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeDeepRight) to omit the undesired keys

```js
let obj1 = { age: 40, contact: { email: 'baa@example.com' }}
let obj2 = { name: 'fred', age: 10, contact: { email: 'moo@example.com' }}

let ommitKeys = Object.keys(obj2).filter(key=> !obj1[key])

let concatValues = (k, l, r) =>  k == 'values' ? R.concat(l, r) : r

let output = R.omit(ommitKeys, R.mergeDeepRight(concatValues, obj1, obj2,))


console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

[**Demo**](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?let%20concatValues%20%3D%20%28k%2C%20l%2C%20r%29%20%3D%3E%20%20k%20%3D%3D%20%27values%27%20%3F%20R.concat%28l%2C%20r%29%20%3A%20r%0A%0AR.omit%28%5B%27name%27%5D%2CmergeDeepRight%28concatValues%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20age%3A%2040%2C%20contact%3A%20%7B%20email%3A%20%27baa%40example.com%27%20%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27fred%27%2C%20age%3A%2010%2C%20contact%3A%20%7B%20email%3A%20%27moo%40example.com%27%20%7D%7D%2C%0A%29%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20true%2C%20b%3A%20true%2C%20c%3A%20%7B%20thing%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%20values%3A%20%5B10%2C%2020%2C%2015%2C%2035%5D%20%7D%7D)

Here ommitedKeys variable holds all the keys which are not present in Object1,

Alternate is to use [Pick](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick)

```js
let obj1 = { age: 40, contact: { email: 'baa@example.com' }}
let obj2 = { name: 'fred', age: 10, contact: { email: 'moo@example.com' }}

let desiredKeys = Object.keys(obj1)

let concatValues = (k, l, r) =>  k == 'values' ? R.concat(l, r) : r

let output = R.pick(desiredKeys, R.mergeDeepRight(concatValues, obj1, obj2,))


console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```